# php barcode scanning text field

Tags: php

Assuming, I have a barcode scanner purchased, having correct code/html with form to catch the string from the scanner, (I want to have my barcode experience for the first time). Can I scan a barcode on a book or any other on a food item package or anything, using my barcode scanner and take that string to the text field on my webpage? 
Thanks.

Comment: yes you can scan your barcode to machine @Tina

Comment: I do mean not barcodes created by me. I mean barcodes that I generally find on books, products etc. that are printed by other people? @MayankVadiya

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken Bar Code scanners just act as Keyboards. They will only fill the input fields with the Bar Code number. So:

1. Connect the Bar Code scanner.
2. You need to make a page with Text Input.
3. Put the cursor on that Input and scan.
4. The Input will be filled with that number.
5. Then you can do whatever you want with that number, like: Matching that number with the products in your database and display it's details. You need to have programming knowledge for this work.

Comment: http://www.synet.sk/php/en/280-barcode-reader-scanner-in-php according to this popular article, I know that I do not need to code for getting the captured barcode string from scanner to  my webpage. It is automatically done by the scanner hardware. I just need to use POST method to process it . Am I correct?

Comment: You need to make a form and process it whether its POST or GET.